# HubSection without DataTemplate (or can you have a form in a HubSection)?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1

Porting an iOS app and I may be abusing the hub control; but I have a very simple app where I'd like a form to be in a hub section. However it seems like it must be wrapped in a DataTemplate and once it is the form's TextBox controls do not show up in the code behind C# file?

```
<HubSection x:Uid="HubSection1" Header="SETTINGS"
                    DataContext="{Binding Groups[2]}" HeaderTemplate="{ThemeResource HubSectionHeaderTemplate}">
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,20,0">
                    <TextBlock Text="api base uri" FontSize="21" TextWrapping="NoWrap"/>
                    <TextBox Name="apiBaseUriTextBox" Margin="0,0,0,10" TextWrapping="Wrap" PlaceholderText="api base uri" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="api key" FontSize="21" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Margin="0,0,0,10"/>
                    <TextBox Name="apiKeyTextBox" Margin="0,0,0,10" TextWrapping="Wrap" PlaceholderText="api key" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="api secret" FontSize="21" TextWrapping="NoWrap"/>
                    <TextBox Name="apiSecretTextBox" Margin="0,0,0,10" TextWrapping="Wrap" PlaceholderText="api secret" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                    <Button Click="SettingsSaveClickHandler" 
                        Content="Save" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,20,0,0"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </HubSection>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to put the form directly in the HubSection's DataTemplate then the best way to access the values is by [data binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh758318(v=win.10).aspx) the TextBoxes to properties in your DataContext. The other option would be to crawl the visual tree by calling the [VisualTreeHelper](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.visualtreehelper.aspx) from your button's SettingsSaveClickHandler

Another option would be to create your form as a UserControl and then host the completed form in the HubSection's DataTemplate. Again, you can bind it to the DataContext to connect to the underlying data.